# Graphene API response is `None` when requesting custom Field

Tags: python-3.x, graphql, graphene-python

I'm trying to learn graphene-python, and have a very simple api set up to GET "hello" or "goodbye" `Message` `graphene.Field`s to all users or a specified user. I want each `Message` to have a field which is another `Metadata`, another `graphene.Field`. But when I make API calls which request `Metadata`, I get a `None` response from my API. The more general question is, **how can I have a custom `graphene.Field`, which itself has variables that are `graphene.Field`s, and how do I resolve these variables?**

Here is my sample API code:

```
import graphene
from uuid import uuid4
import time


users = ['A', 'B',' C']

# describes message metadata
class Metadata(graphene.ObjectType):
    time_sent = graphene.Int()
    uuid = graphene.String()

    def resolve_timeSent(parent, info):
        return int(time.time())

    def resolve_uuid(parent, info):
        return uuid4().hex

# basic message model
# contains message content and metadata
class Message(graphene.ObjectType):
    content = graphene.String()
    metadata = graphene.Field(Metadata)

    def resolve_metadata(parent, info):
        return Metadata()


# query schema
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    # Return a list of message objects
    helloTo = graphene.Field(Message, user=graphene.String(required=True))
    helloAll = graphene.List(Message)
    goodbyeTo = graphene.Field(Message, user=graphene.String(required=True))
    goodbyeAll = graphene.List(Message)

    ###
    # resolvers
    ###

    def resolve_helloTo(self, info, user):
        data = Message(f"hello, {user}", int(time.time()))
        return data

    def resolve_helloAll(self, info):
        data = [Message(f"hello, {u}!", int(time.time())) for u in users]
        return data

    def resolve_goodbyeTo(self, info, user):
        data = Message(f"goodbye, {user}", int(time.time()))
        return data

    def resolve_goodbyeAll(self, info):
        data = [Message(f"goodbye, {u}!", int(time.time())) for u in users]
        return data

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

The query

```
query {
  helloTo(user: "STRANGER") {
    content
  }
}
```

Returns a proper response of

```
{
    "helloTo": {
        "content": "hello, STRANGER"
    }
}
```

But the queries

```
    query {
      helloTo(user: "jack wolf") {
        content
        metadata
      }
    }
```

and

```
    query {
      helloTo(user: "jack wolf") {
        content
        metadata {
            time_sent
            uuid
        }
      }
    }
```

Both return `None`.

How can I fix this? Thank you!